# Нужно ли перед тире ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*Но есть те, кто смог устоять(,) — выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя.*

Не понимаю, нужно ли перед тире ставить запятую? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая *нужна* для "закрытия обособляемого оборота", как говорят в таких случаях, - поскольку в этом месте предложение не заканчивается, но придаточное - завершается. Тире здесь факультативно; без него очевидно, что запятая нужна; однако без тире требуется дополнительное местоимение (, они выжили), либо согласование по числу (смогли).

Comment: причислять придаточное к обособляемым оборотам - это по сути правильно, но очень непривычно по систематике)))

Answer (score 2):

Здесь скорее тире стоит убрать, а запятая бесспорна, она закрывает придаточное. В таких случаях её даже тире не "съедает".

Answer (score 1):

Тире можно поставить, запятая в любом случае обязательна.

Фраза очень неграмотная, зачем там "есть"? Уберем придаточное: *Но есть те – выжили, стерпели...*

Answer (score 1):

Сразу признаюсь, что я, как и все участники, почему-то подумал, что запятая обязательна на основании закрытия придаточной части. Хотя, в принципе, я даже не думал достаточно много над этим вопросом.

В общем, я считаю, что запятая здесь неуместна конкретно на основании **придаточной части**. Почему? А вы попробуйте убрать нашу "придаточную часть" и посмотрите, что получится:

**Но есть те (тут она была) выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя**.

Как-то не очень, не правда ли???

Полагаю, что сочетание **выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя** должно относиться к придаточной части и быть, скажем, группой сказуемых,  однородных по отношению к "смог устоять". Здесь, опять же, можно привести кучу вариантов, основанных на этой конструкции. Можно даже весь оборот переделать в группу однородных сказуемых при обобщающем слове. Да и вообще, оборот, по-моему, употреблен ненормативно в плане формы глаголов.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, можно так исправить предожение: Но есть те, кто смогли устоять, – выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя.

Тогда запятая ставится обязательно, а тире авторское.

Мне кажется, что должно быть согласование глаголов во мн. числе: смогли, выжили, устояли.

Похожее согласование местоимения с глаголом (кто смогли): Это были те, кто смогли пробиться с боями через Днестр в Румынию.

Comment: Это не будет _исправлением_, хотя в данном конкретном случае вариант множественного числа тоже возможен (поскольку множ. число глагола в основном предложении). http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_05

Comment: P. S. При убранном тире - да, требуются исправления: понадобится местоимение "они", которое оно замещает. Но изменять число на множественное после этого не обязательно.

Comment: По Вашей ссылке указано, что обе формы возможны. Я думаю, что в данном случае выбор мн. числа связан с тем, что остальные глаголы употреблены во мн. числе. Именно разное число у глаголов создает ощущение, что предложение не очень правильное. Может быть, исправление необязательное, но мне кажется, что очень желательное.

Comment: Так сейчас чаще говорят московские дикторы, поэтому может так казаться. Для меня же после этого местоимения  естественнее единственное число, которое, к тому же, возможно почти всегда.

Comment: Извините, я не настаиваю на своей точке зрения, наверное, Вам виднее. И еще. Я написала, что исправляю предложение, так как  его уже назвали здесь  "неграмотным".  Я бы сказала, что не то что оно неграмотное, но не очень корректное. Еще раз извините, что наши мнения не совпадают.

Comment: И еще по поводу тире. Вот предложение без тире: Но есть те, кто смогли устоять, выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя. Здесь все глаголы входят в придаточное предложение.

Comment: Да, в нём все глаголы нужно приводить к одному времени, либо добавлять местоимение (тогда присоединится самостоятельное предложение).

Comment: Возможно, но  пауза в речи, обозначенная тире, не изменить общее восприятие предложения: мы всё равно будем слышать несогласованные в числе глаголы.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, здесь возможны два варианта пунктуации?

1 вариант (без запятой).

*Но есть те, кто смог устоять — выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя*.

Если рассматривать слова после тире как входящие в придаточное предложение и поясняющие, что значит "смог устоять":

смог устоять, а именно (то есть) выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя_.

2 вариант (с запятой).

Но есть те, кто смог устоять, — выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя.

Если рассматривать часть после тире как присоединительное предложение к сложноподчиненному предложению (Но есть те, кто смог устоять,), которое является, в свою очередь, частью всего даннного сложносочиненного предложения, часть которого после тире носит присоединительный характер (присоединение без союза) и представляет собой дополнительное сообщение.

(Если возможны эти два варианта, то предложения в каждом случае произносятся с разной интонацией.)

Например, на "Грамоте. РУ" приводятся два варианта пунктуации в зависимости от вкладываемого смысла.

_Здравствуйте. Нужна ли запятая на месте скобок? Где можно почитать о постановках запятой в таких случаях? Это нормально, если ты хочешь только читать книги или только рисовать(,) — учитель всегда поможет.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Ставить или не ставить запятую, зависит от смысла предложения, а именно о том, к чему относятся слова учитель всегда поможет.

Если имеется в виду: если ты хочешь только читать книги или только рисовать — учитель всегда поможет (читать и рисовать), то запятая перед тире не нужна.

Если имеется в виду: Это нормально, если ты хочешь только читать книги или только рисовать, — учитель всегда поможет (справиться с этой ситуацией и найти баланс между желанием и необходимостью), то запятая перед тире нужна_.