# Может ли присоединительное тире ставиться между однородными сказуемыми?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, однородные-члены

Меня заинтересовало предложение, которое я нашла в Правилах Розенталя: *Внезапно мальчик исчез — умер, или, возможно, его похитили.*

Его можно немного перестроить: *Внезапно мальчик исчез — умер или был похищен.*

Можно ли считать, что здесь присоединительное тире разделяет однородные сказуемые?

А сам вопрос опять связан с предыдущим вопросом: *Но есть те, кто смогли устоять — выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя* (это редактированный вариант заданного вопроса).

[Нужно ли перед тире ставить запятую? Не понимаю - объясните, пожалуйста](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452623/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)

Может быть, здесь тоже  однородные сказуемые и тогда запятая не нужна?

Или еще вариант:  присоединительный однородный ряд "выжили, стерпели" раскрывает (дополняет) содержание сказуемого  "смогли устоять".

Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 1):

Да уж, непростая конструкция.

На мой взгляд, тире здесь вводит уточняющий оборот. Для себя объяснил это сравнением со следующим случаем, сходным по значению с данным, где используется слово "наверное", достаточно часто используемое при уточнении:

**Внезапно мальчик исчез, *наверное* умер или, возможно, был похищен**.

Зададим соответствующие вопросы:

*Внезапно мальчик исчез (что подразумевает под собой его исчезновение? В нашем случае смерть или похищение), **наверное умер** или **был похищен** кем-то*.

Тире же в данном случае вполне уместно, но на основании **уточняющешо оборота**. Сказуемые, кстати, действительно однородны, причём **все**.

Comment: Спасибо. Сказуемые могут считаться  грамматически однородными, но не всегда они однородны по смыслу. Здесь, вероятно, такая ситуация: вводные слова указывают не на реальное, а на предположительные действия. Но меня интересует и наше предложение (из предыдущего вопроса): можно ли в нем поставить только тире, как и здесь. "Но есть те, кто смогли устоять — выжили, стерпели это непосильное бремя". Как Вы думаете? В принципе можно считать, что присоединительный ряд раскрывает содержание глагола "выстояли".

Comment: Сейчас опубликую ответ к Вашему предыдущему вопросу, ибо не хочется засорять комментарии. Да и не так удобно.